Problem In Login Module In Firebase login anynoumsly not working
Problem In Login Module In Firebase anonymous login not working in the emulator.

When I Run Code with 'await'
with 'await' stuck app at black screen
Run without 'await'
App is installed successfully but when I press on guest it will not work
once I press on guest it will look like this
main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_score/auth/customer_signup.dart';
import 'package:multi_score/main_screens/customer_home.dart';
import 'package:multi_score/main_screens/supplier_home.dart';
import 'package:multi_score/main_screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //home: WelcomeScreen(),
      initialRoute: '/welcome_screen',
      routes: {
        '/welcome_screen':(context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
        '/customer_home':(context) => const CustomerHomeScreen(),
        '/supplier_home':(context) => const SupplierHomeScreen(),
        '/customer_signup':(context) => const CustomerRagister(),
      },
    );
  }
}


Please find the below logs for the issue
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53308/_gBL46eXSKI=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
E/flutter ( 5501): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
E/flutter ( 5501):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
E/flutter ( 5501):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
E/flutter ( 5501):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/flutter ( 5501):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/flutter ( 5501):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter ( 5501): , null)
E/flutter ( 5501): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5501): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 5501): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5501): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 5501): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5501): 
D/ProfileInstaller( 5501): Installing profile for com.example.multi_score
E/flutter ( 5501): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
E/flutter ( 5501): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:193:5)
E/flutter ( 5501): #1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:56:41)
E/flutter ( 5501): #2      FirebaseAuth.instance (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:38:47)
E/flutter ( 5501): #3      _WelcomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:multi_score/main_screens/welcome_screen.dart:223:46)
E/flutter ( 5501): #4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
E/flutter ( 5501): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:24)
E/flutter ( 5501): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
E/flutter ( 5501): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
E/flutter ( 5501): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:670:9)
E/flutter ( 5501): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter ( 5501): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter ( 5501): #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
E/flutter ( 5501): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 5501): #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:495:19)
E/flutter ( 5501): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:475:22)
E/flutter ( 5501): #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:430:11)
E/flutter ( 5501): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): #19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:383:5)
E/flutter ( 5501): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:330:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:299:9)
E/flutter ( 5501): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
E/flutter ( 5501): #23     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:429:7)
E/flutter ( 5501): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
E/flutter ( 5501): 

pubspec.yaml
name: multi_score
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.2 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  image_picker: ^1.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.3
  firebase_core: ^2.30.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
    - images/men/
    - images/try/
    - images/inapp/
    - images/women/
    - images/shoes/
    - images/electronics/
    - images/beauty/
    - images/kids/
    - images/homegarden/
    - images/accessories/
    - images/bags/


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
  fonts:
    - family: Acme
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Acme_Regular.ttf


please share error logs as well to help you better

Ok I Add The Error logs and also you can see i share photos of error and outputs on emulator.

can you please share pubspec.yaml file which has firebase packages?

Okk I add the 'pubspec.yaml' file

The main part of the error message is:

Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.

So it looks like the Firebase client can't find its configuration information. Did you follow the setup process that's outlined in the documentation here? That should result in a firebase_options.dart file, which the Flutter SDK can then use to read the configuration values.

In My project value.xml is not showing

That's expected. But if you follow the instructions that I linked, it'll create the necessary configuration files for you.

Okk Will Try to solve
